# Curl with log and parameters inside a txt file in the same folder

Tags: bash, curl, sh

I'm building a .sh script to run curls based on the items (per line) placed in on a file fileWithItems.txt.
This is the script I built:

```
declare -a array
#assuming fileWithItems.txt contains one element per line to be used in the url is in the same folder as this .sh
mapfile -t array < fileWithItems.txt
host="localhost"
port="PORT"

i=0
while [ ${i} -lt ${#array[@]} ] ; do 
curl -X PUT "$host:$port/path1/${array[$i]}/refresh" > log.txt
((i++))
done
```

Seem that the curl is not being built properly. How could it be optimized?

Comment: What's the error? btw you don't need to build array. Just read file in a while loop and call `curl` for each line.

Comment: @anubhava hmmm didn't know that would be possble. But I need to get a string from each line and place it in the middle of the curl string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate further from my comments, you can do it like this:

```
host="localhost"
port="PORT"

while IFS= read -r line; do
   curl -X PUT "$host:$port/path1/$line/refresh"
done < fileWithItems.txt > log.txt
```

Please note placement of `> log.txt` after `done` so that you don't overwrite same file every time.